# bash:firebase command not found in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to run a "firebase init functions" in android studio terminal but it is showing firebase command not found. I have also checked in google but unfortunately did not find any related question or answer.

Comment: Have you installed Firebase tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't installed firebase tools .to do so type this in your terminal 
First install node js from nodejs.org

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Now you can login using `firebase login`  and after login you can now run `firebase init`

Comment: @G griffo Once again i install the firebase-tools but after installation i tried to run the command firebase login still it shows firebase command not found

Comment: and is your npm working? first did npm install - firebase-tools return an error

Comment: @G griffo yes it is returning an error while installing npm install - firebase-tools.npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/- - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '-@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nabil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-17T10_38_56_047Z-debug.log

Comment: If you're on Linux sudo npm install -g firebase-tools .requires super user

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Sorry had not read the log properly you have to install node js which installs npm and then run command to install firebase tools

Comment: I got the solution by adding node js path in system environment